unpacking nested tuples after Spark RDD join
The resources for this are scarce and I'm not sure that there's a solution to this issue.
Suppose you have 3 simple RDD's. Or more specifically 3 PairRDD's.
val rdd1: RDD[(Int, Int)] = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,0),(2,0),(3,0),(4,0),(5,0)))
val rdd2: RDD[(Int, Int)] = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1)))
val rdd3: RDD[(Int, Int)] = sc.parallelize(Seq((1,2),(2,2),(3,2),(4,2),(5,2)))

rdd1              rdd2              rdd3
+------+------+   +------+------+   +------+------+
| K    | V    |   | K    | V    |   | K    | V    |
+------+------+   +------+------+   +------+------+
|    1 |    0 |   |    1 |    1 |   |    1 |    2 |
|    2 |    0 |   |    2 |    1 |   |    2 |    2 |
|    3 |    0 |   |    3 |    1 |   |    3 |    2 |
|    4 |    0 |   |    4 |    1 |   |    4 |    2 |
|    5 |    0 |   |    5 |    1 |   |    5 |    2 |
+------+------+   +------+------+   +------+------+

The problem arises when one tries to join all 3 RDD's. When we join them, we get the following structure
val joinedRdd: RDD[(Int,((Int, Int), Int))] = rdd1.join(rdd2).join(rdd3)

joinedRdd
+------+----------------+
| K    | V              |
+------+----------------+  
|    1 |   ((0, 1), 2)  |
|    2 |   ((0, 1), 2)  |
|    3 |   ((0, 1), 2)  |
|    4 |   ((0, 1), 2)  |
|    5 |   ((0, 1), 2)  |
+------+----------------+

The question is as follows: suppose you have n RDDs that you would like to join, the result of the join will be n-1 nested tuples. How would you approach the issue of unpacking the nested tuples. Unnesting these values is proving to be very difficult. Pattern matching requires that you know the structure of the tuple you're unnesting, I don't have that luxury.
Bonus question: in the higher level API's of Spark (the dataframe/dataset API's), is this issue handled in the codegen? As in, does the codegen take into account the expected output structure in the codegen process?

If our task flatten random count tuple or ints maybe productIterator will be usefull in this case. All Tuples realized interface Product, then we can iterate over tuple via productIterator method.
def flat(el: Product): List[Int] = {
    el.productIterator.foldLeft(List[Int]()) {
      (acc, v) => {
       v match {
         case v: Int => acc ++ List(v)
         case v: Product => acc ++ flat(v)
       }
      }
    }
}

joinedRdd.collect().foreach(println)
joinedRdd.map(flat).collect().foreach(println)

(1,((0,1),2))
(2,((0,1),2))
(3,((0,1),2))
(4,((0,1),2))
(5,((0,1),2))

List(1, 0, 1, 2)
List(2, 0, 1, 2)
List(3, 0, 1, 2)
List(4, 0, 1, 2)
List(5, 0, 1, 2)

